# How would I go about creating this jump page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

> *Note: I'm a total novice at any coding. I'm just a dumb amature graphic designer. I've only ever created a page that lets me copy the
> the most common phrases I had to leave in notes all day. I struggled
> with it.*

I'm trying to create this page that lets input something into a text field, and it applies it to defined URLS attached to buttons, that will bring me to those pages. Since I struggle to describe it, please see this visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZplRK.jpg

I've tried co-opting some scripts for similar problems, but with no luck. (See below for examples before I edited them ). I included them to see if I was on the right track whatsoever. I know I'm gonna have an issue with multiple functions, probably?

```html
<script type="javascript">
function goToPage(var url = '')
{
    var initial = "http://example.com";
    var extension = "html";

    window.location(initial+url+extension);
}
</script>

<form name="something" action="#">
Label <input type="text" name="url" value="" onchange="goToPage(this.value)">
</form>
```

```html
<SCRIPT type="javascript">
function goToPage(var url = '')
{
var initial = "https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails";
var extension = "";

window.location(initial+url+extension);
}
</SCRIPT>
<TITLE>Redirect 1</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
<FORM name="jump" action="#">
CMS ID:
<INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onSubmit="goToPage(this.value)">
<INPUT type="submit" value="GO">
```

That's where I at. I'm just tired of typing the same long URLs all day at work, and messing up more than half the time. I have no clue what the solution is - Javascript? HTML? CSS? Just trying to seek the DIY answer before looking on how to hire someone to make it. Which I have no clue how to do either but that's another question for later.

Thanks for helping / apologies for possibly super dumb questions.

Comment: 1. you don't `var` in a function declaration (`goToPage`). 2. to change the URL you do `window.location.href = 'http://foo.bar';`.  3. fixing (2) and (3) would mean `goToPage` will take you to the new URL every time the input value changes. That one instead should simply set a variable. You can then add `onclick`s to some buttons, build the URLs and do `window.location.here = 'http://foo.bar' + idVariable;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```js
// grab the input element
const input = document.getElementById("cmsId");

// grab all links that need to be updated accordingly
// when value inside input element changes
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

// create a handler that listens for changes when
// you type some text into the input element
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  // grab value inside input elemenet
  const value = event.target.value;

  // iterate through all links and update
  // the inner text + href attribute accordingly
  // NOTE: `baseUrl` for each link is stored in a
  // `data-*` attribute
  links.forEach((link) => {
    const baseUrl = link.dataset.url;
    const url = baseUrl + value;

    link.innerText = url;
    link.href = url;
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Use a simple input element here, no need for a form -->
<div>CMS ID: <input id="cmsId" type="text" /></div>

<div>
  <!-- No need to create buttons, simple anchor elements will work just fine -->
  <a
    id="main"
    href="#"
    target="_blank"
    data-url="https://cmss.company.com/client/viewclientdetails/"
  >
    https://cmss.company.com/client/viewclientdetails/
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a
    id="notes"
    href="#"
    target="_blank"
    data-url="https://cmss.company.com/client/viewnotes/"
  >
    https://cmss.company.com/client/viewnotes/
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a
    id="docs"
    href="#"
    target="_blank"
    data-url="https://cmss.company.com/client/documentsall/"
  >
    https://cmss.company.com/client/documentsall/
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a
    id="activity"
    href="#"
    target="_blank"
    data-url="https://cmss.company.com/client/viewactivityledger/"
  >
    https://cmss.company.com/client/viewactivityledger/
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much the input and solution - I like this simplicity of this one a lot; but I couldn't get it work in the way like it does in the _Run Code Snippet_ - so I'm gonna come back to this one with a fresh brain here.

Comment: @charles_dempsey what is the issue you're having?

Comment: > everything looked correct but I couldn't get it to update when I tested it out with the real links? I'm probably just not getting the top part configured right.  Or something adding the two together that isn't meshing. This isn't my strong suit for sure. hah.

Comment: Is this something you could put on [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io) and share? Otherwise it's hard to tell what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are working with only the "main" button as I can see (as it goes to viewclientdetails). You are missing a "/" sign after *var initial*. So, assuming that you can implement the same functionality of the main button to the other buttons, here's what you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToPage(var url = '')
{
var initial = "https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails/"; //I added the slash 

var extension = "";

window.location(initial+url+extension);
}
</script>
<TITLE>Redirect 1</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
<FORM name="jump" action="#">
CMS ID:
<INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onSubmit="goToPage(this.value)">
<INPUT type="submit" value="GO"> //you need 4 buttons here
```

You cannot have an *input type="submit"* here, since you will need four buttons. Submit works like a form submission. Add four buttons, then for each button's onClick property add the desired redirect url. You will need to get the value for the input field using an ID tag.

An example of what I am trying to say is given below:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onMainButtonClicked()
    {
    var cmsid= document.getElementById("cmsID").value;
    var initial = "https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails/"; //I added the slash 
    
    var extension = "";
    
    window.location(initial+cmsid+extension);
    }
    function onNotesButtonClicked()
    {
    ...
    }
    function onDocsButtonClicked()
    {
    ...
    }
    function onActivityButtonClicked()
    {
    ...
    }
    </script>
    <TITLE>Redirect 1</TITLE>
    <BASE HREF="https://cms.example.com/client/viewcasedetails">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <P>
    <FORM name="jump" action="#">
    CMS ID:
    <INPUT type="text" id="cmsID" name="url" value="">
    <button onclick="onMainButtonClicked()">Main</button>
    <button onclick="onNotesButtonClicked()">Notes</button>
    <button onclick="onDocsButtonClicked()">Docs</button>
    <button onclick="onActivityButtonClicked()">Activity</button>
```

There are much better ways to implement this, but this is a very simple implementation.